# How to print / log all git commits messages from certain commit?

Tags: git

I need to print out all git messages from certain git commit to text file.

I've looked into answers here on Stackoverflow but couldn't find one that works for conditions I mention.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following command in git terminal:

```
git log --reverse --pretty=%s 487fc18... > ../log.txt
```

If you want to print all commits for "today" you can use command like:

```
git log --reverse --pretty=%s --since=midnight > ../log.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Git does not provide any utility to direct any of its output to a file.

Instead, like virtually all *nix tools, it uses the [standard output streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) for all of its output, allowing you to use traditional [shell output redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) to redirect these streams to a file of your choice.

In Bash, to redirect the logs for a specific commit, you would use the `>` to direct standard output to a file:

```
git log <commit_id> > <output_file>
```

Comment: `git log <commit_id>` will also return the log for all parent commits (speaks: previous commits). If you only want the log for one single commit and nothing more use `git log -1 <commit_id>`.